# Google Maps JS API V3 - Create map and insert fake labels over locations

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm mocking up an HTML5 web app and I need to incorporate a map with specific locations marked off with custom banners. For the sake of the mockup, I just need to have the default location markers replaced with some sort of graphic of my choosing. How would I do this?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and is unlikely to get good responses without more detail. For instance: have you looked at the developer docs? (they are quite good), if so do you have a specific question about some aspect you are having trouble with? If you have code you are working on, post it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The [Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) has [a custom marker icon example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple) ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)). You can use it as a starting point for your own code.